# C++ Printing DWORD_PTR* String to File

Tags: c++, string, io, inline-assembly

I've made a function that takes a DWORD_PTR* (holds the address of a string that we got using inline assembly) and a int (the size of the string/char*)

The function should simply get the data in DWORD_PTR* and then print it to a file as a string...

However... It's printing a bunch of numbers in sets of 4 instead... Here's an example of the output (first few lines)...

```
4e65 7720 5061 636b 6574 2052 6563 6569
7665 6420 6f66 2053 697a 653a 2031 380d
0a03 1404 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0007 140d 0a0d 0a4e 6577 2050 6163 6b65
7420 5265 6365 6976 6564 206f 6620 5369
7a65 3a20 340d 0a01 0001 000d 0a0d 0a4e
6577 2050 6163 6b65 7420 5265 6365 6976
6564 206f 6620 5369 7a65 3a20 3138 0d0a
```

Here's the function...

```
void PrintDataString(const DWORD_PTR* data_address, const int data_size)
{
    const char* data = ((char*)(data_address));

    // Open our Log File...
    std::ofstream log_file;
    log_file.open("TheLog.log", std::ios::app);

    for (int i = 0; i < data_size; i++)
    {
        log_file << data[i];
    }

    // Add some spacing for next entry...
    log_file << std::endl << std::endl;

    log_file.close();
}
```

Comment: There's nothing immediately wrong with this, `data_address` is likely pointing to a string containing exactly what your output is.

Comment: The data held there is data stored in a assembly register that I pulled in a DWORD_PTR* via the assembly inline command MOV [data_address], EDI. Using OllyDBG, I can look at the exact register, and the data is definitely not what is showing.

Comment: ..."a string containing exactly what your output is. " - which looks suspiciously like a memory dump of a region of memory containing a string (that looks a *lot* like a hex dump, dumping 2 bytes per item, and if you look at each byte, most of them correspond to ASCII characters, e.g. the first set of characters are "New Packet Received of Size: 18" followed by a carriage return and a line feed.

Comment: So does the actual pointer point to a string that begins with "New Packet Received of Size: 18", rather than a string that begins with "4e65 7720 5061 636b 6574 2052 6563 6569"?

Comment: Hmmm in the acctual function I printed this..

log_file << "New Packet Received of Size: " << int(data_size) << std::endl;

Then I would run the above loop that prints each character.

Comment: And, if you just look at "TheLog.log" as a text file, does it contain the text you showed, rather than the first line being "New Packet Received of Size: 18"?  (Do *not* try to look at the file with some program that looks at raw binary data, like a hex dump program or a hex editor; those programs will probably show you a text file beginning with "New Packet Received of Size: 18" as the kind of hex dump you showed.)

Comment: It looks like it's printing the hex values, rather than the string... But whyyyyy

Comment: Wow... I was using Sublime text, seems it converts it... I just switched to notepad and now it looks fine...

Comment: FWIW, if you want different behaviour from Sublime, File -> Reopen With Encoding

Answer (score 1):

As you already discovered, your text viewer (Sublime) was simply displaying the file content in binary hex format instead of as text.

That being said,  why are you using a `DWORD_PTR*` pointer to pass character data around?  `DWORD_PTR` is just an unsigned integer that is large enough to hold a pointer value on all platforms.  Don't confuse that with a real pointer.  You should be passing your function a real pointer to the actual character data:

```
void PrintDataString(const char* data, const int data_size)
{
    // Open our Log File...
    std::ofstream log_file;
    log_file.open("TheLog.log", std::ios::app);

    /*
    for (int i = 0; i < data_size; i++)
    {
        log_file << data[i];
    }
    */
    log_file.write(data, data_size);

    // Add some spacing for next entry...
    log_file << std::endl << std::endl;

    log_file.close();
}
```

**IF** (and I stress IF, because this would be really awkward coding) you are really storing a character pointer value inside a `DWORD_PTR` variable and then passing that variable by address to the function, eg:

```
char *data = ...;
DWORD_PTR address = (DWORD_PTR) data;
void PrintDataString(&address, ...);
```

Then you need to perform an additional dereference operation to get to the character data:

```
void PrintDataString(const DWORD_PTR* data_address, const int data_size)
{
    const char* data = (const char*) *data_address; // <-- note the extra *
    ...
}
```

IF, on the other hand, you are simply type-casting the character data pointer when passing it to the function:

```
char *data = ...;
DWORD_PTR *address = (DWORD_PTR*) data;
void PrintDataString(address, ...);
```

Then you don't need the additional dereference:

```
void PrintDataString(const DWORD_PTR* data_address, const int data_size)
{
    const char* data = (const char*) data_address;
    ...
}
```

Either way, using `DWORD_PTR` in this manner is a very awkward way to pass a character data pointer around.

Answer (score 0):

There are some non-printable characters there - the 00's and 01's, for example - so perhaps Sublime Text decided it was a binary file rather than a text file and showed it to you as binary.

I.e., TheLog.log is *not* a text file; perhaps what's pointed to by the pointer you got is a data structure that contains strings but also contains binary values, or contains buffers for strings that are padded out to a fixed size with nulls, or something such as that.